# Get list all initialized @Named-beans on runtime

Tags: jsf, cdi, omnifaces

I use `javax.inject.Named` and `javax.enterprise.context.*Scoped` plus `org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped` to define the life-scope of my view-beans.

Now I want to get a list of all instantiated beans. First, I thought [this blog-entry](http://www.gregbugaj.com/?p=126) covers this issue, but it only lists `@ManagedBeans`.

Do you know how to list them? Is this possible without being fixed on an implementation or even a version of JavaEE?

PS: I already found `org.omnifaces.cdi.BeanStorage`, but I don't have any idea how to access its map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you're using OmniFaces, you can use [`Beans#getActiveInstances()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.1/org/omnifaces/util/Beans.html#getActiveInstances-java.lang.Class-) method of the [`Beans` utility class](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans) to get all active instances in a given CDI scope.

```
Map<Object, String> activeViewScopedBeans = Beans.getActiveInstances(ViewScoped.class);
// ...
```

The key is the bean instance and the value is the bean name.

For the technically interested, here's the [concrete implementation](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.1/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/BeansLocal.java#L133) of this utility method:

```
public static <S extends Annotation> Map<Object, String> getActiveInstances(BeanManager beanManager, Class<S> scope) {
    Map<Object, String> activeInstances = new HashMap<>();
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class);
    Context context = beanManager.getContext(scope);

    for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
        Object instance = context.get(bean);

        if (instance != null) {
            activeInstances.put(instance, bean.getName());
        }
    }

    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(activeInstances);
}
```

The `BeanStorage` is for internal usage only. Moreover, it's not listed in the [showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org).