# How do you find CDI beans of/in the current view (scope)?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, view-scope, seam3

In a **Java EE 6, CDI 1.1.x, Seam 3 etc. environment**, we need to find all CDI beans of the current view (`@ViewScoped`). What I have tried so far is using:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ViewHelper
{
    @Inject
    private BeanManager beanManager;

    public doSomethingWithTheBeanInstances()
    {
        Set<Bean<?>> beans = this.getBeanManager().getBeans( 
            Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>(){}
        );

        // do something
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this returns *all* beans it manages.

I need to find only those **within the scope of the current view** and - that would be ideal - only those that implement a specific interface (inherited over over multiple hierarchy levels).

What's the way to do it?

Note since CDI has no view scope, we're using **Seam 3** to be able to annotate all our view-scoped beans like:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class ResultManagerColumnHandler extends BaseColumnHandler
{
    ....
}
```

The above would be an instance to look for (the `@ViewScoped` is a CDI replacement by Seam 3).

How can it be done?

Comment: Just a quick thought - if all those beans you want implement specific interface, then they have the Type of that interface, so you could perchance do `@Inject Instance<YourInterfaceType> instances`. Now, because `Instance` implements Iterable, you should be able to iterate over all the instances.

Comment: The problem still is **HOW** do I get only those within the current view without knowing the specific bean names (EL names and/or class names)...???

Comment: I'm not familiar with Seam3, but does `Context context = beanManager.getContext(ViewScoped.class);` return a valid `Context`? (i.e. not null nor an exception). If that part works, then I can post an answer how to use it to get the currently active beans.

Comment: Siliarus stole my answer, but if `Context` would be valid, then it basically boils down to the approach as shown in his post. It has been in [OmniFaces](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/2.6/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/util/BeansLocal.java#L152) for ages (authored by yours truly).

Comment: Any luck? I didn't got any feedback on my first comment. At least I remembered this dupe http://stackoverflow.com/q/33478927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with Seam, but from CDI standpoint, this is what I would try. However, bean it mind that it will **only work if `beanManager.getContext(ViewScoped.class);` returns a valid context instance for you**:

```
@Inject
BeanManager bm;

public List<Object> getAllViewScoped() {
    List<Object> allBeans = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(Object.class);
    // NOTE - context has to be active when you try this
    Context context = bm.getContext(ViewScoped.class);

    for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
        Object instance = context.get(bean);
        if (instance != null) {
            allBeans.add(instance);
        }
    }

    return allBeans;
}
```

You also asked to only obtain beans that implement certain interface. For that, simply modify the code line retrieving all beans with desired type:

```
Set<Bean<?>> beans = bm.getBeans(MyInterface.class);
```

Comment: Yea, thanks. I was trying the code in my IDE for AppScoped and forgot to edit this piece after pasting.